# How to edit jqwidgets jquery grid cellclassname/css using row id and column name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jquery-widgets

```
{
    text: 'sell',
    datafield: 'Sales',
    width: '3%',
    columntype: 'button',
    filterable: false,
    cellsrenderer: function(row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
        return '<i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

    },
    buttonclick: function(rowData) {
        var dataRecord = $("#ProductPriceList").jqxGrid('getrowdata', rowData);

        sellIndex = $("#ProductPriceList").jqxGrid('getrowboundindex', rowData);
    }

},
{
    text: 'Code',
    datafield: 'ProductCode',
    columntype: 'textbox',
    filtercondition: 'contains',
    width: '5%'
}
```

how do I change the CSS(background color) of the cell Code on the row that has Id sellIndex via sell button click?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good solution but I applied this:

- Set sellIndex=-1 initially

added this under Sales buttonclick

```
sellIndex = $("#ProductPriceList").jqxGrid('getrowboundindex', rowData);

$("#ProductPriceList").jqxGrid('updatebounddata');
```

and this under Code

```
 cellsrenderer:
    function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) 
                               {
                                    if (sellIndex != -1)
                                    {
    
                                        if (row == sellIndex) {
                                            return '<br>&nbsp<span class="chosen">' + value + ' </span>';
                                        } else {
                                            return '<br>&nbsp' + value ;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }
```